# not able to deploy crystal report Visual Studio 2010 website at webserver

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have developed my application in vs10 using crystal report 13.0.2000.0, my Application works fine on development machine, but after deployment on webserver I m getting following error:

Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {4DB2E2BB-78E6-4AEA-BEFB-FDAAB610FD1B} failed due to the following error: 80070005 Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

the environment at server is Windows 2008 R2 in 32 bit.

I have installed following

http://downloads.businessobjects.com/akdlm/cr4vs2010/CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_2.zip

pls help me on this issue.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Issue was resolved after giving the IIS User access to the C:\Windows\Temp folder. Crystal uses this directory and if IIS user does not have access, you might get above error.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe IIS user or ASP.NET user doesn't have the right to access Reports Folder, please check

Comment: what I was missing was providing full control to the IIS user and ASP.NET user on temp directory of windows. I requested my web space provider to give full control to everyone on temp directory of windows and the things worked.